# What is the most pythonic way to search for a value in a dictionary of dictionaries with different keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, search

How can I find in a list of dictionaries that it contain at least one value.

I found a couple of answers to this question but in all of them they suppose you know the key name in this case I don't know what's the name of the key.

Example:

```
 dic_list = [
              {u'12': False, u'3': True, u'6': False, u'9': False},
              {u'12': False, u'3': False, u'6': False, u'9': False}
            ]
```

How can I return True if there's at least one True as a value in either of these dictionaries without having to do a nested for loop?

Comment: `any(True in d for d in dic_list)` would do that.

Comment: It's looks for keys. If you want to look for the values use `any(True in d.values() ..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With builtin `any` function:

```
has_true = any(True in d.values() for d in dic_list)
```